# How to document Ruby code using Doxygen?

Tags: ruby, documentation, doxygen, auto-generate

Question: How can I document Ruby code using Doxygen?

Disclaimer: I know ruby already has a system for documentation built in and there are probably other ways to do it as well, but the specific constraint I am operating under is how to get Doxygen to do the job (assuming it is possible).

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Short answer, no.  Long answer, still no.  Doxygen will come to Ruby eventually, but I don't have the sense that it's going to happen any time soon.  In the short term, you're stuck with either RDoc or YARD.

Comment: Nice no-frills blunt answer. +1

Comment: YARD is amazing, I'd go with that :)

Answer (score 2):

You can try out a testing version at https://github.com/fourmond/doxygen-ruby-patch. It is still experimental though, but through testing it will hopefully be integrated into mainstream doxygen.

Comment: "fourmond authored 3 years ago", I guess this never went back into upstream?